# What is the minimum/suggested sequence length for training an LSTM?

Tags: deep-learning, rnn, lstm

My dataset consists of short videos of 4/5 time-steps each (frames), and the problem is classifying this video (multi-label classification). The idea is to use an LSTM but I'm wondering if the sequence length is not enough.
 What are the suggested sequence length? May 4/5 time steps be enough?

P.S. could you please post some link to scientific articles to endorse your claims?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LSTMs would run into problems beyond 500 time steps. 
original paper by [Hochreiter and Schmidhuber](http://www.bioinf.jku.at/publications/older/2604.pdf): "LSTM can learn to bridge minimal time lags in excess of 1000 discrete time steps."

Example: Your video is 60 seconds long. I would start by encoding 5 frames per second using a CNN (use resnet (SEnets have better performance but i havent read the paper) till the layer just before final affine layer which feeds into the softmax encode your images. Use these encodings as inputs in a GRU (Hence a 300 time steps for this GRU) and use its final state to make the class prediction (use a separate loss for each label?)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I updated my question in order to ad some details.

Comment: what do you mean by 4 - 5 time steps. I know that video classification could be attempted by considering frames of the static images but that brings in the question of at what fps are you capturing those frames? editing answer as per new information

Comment: I mean 4-5 frames per video... It's a real dataset I cannot change it or get more frames...

Comment: use an ensemble. a large one. use a pretrained resnet on frames but while training make the gradients flow to all the layers of resnet. then use LSTM on the representations of each frame and also use a deep affine and CNN. ensemble the results. 4 - 5 frames per video can give you only so much representation power if they are not taken in some common pattern which directly affects the classifications. Good luck